# CENTERED HTML content box with a width and height limit?

Tags: html

I need what is listed as the question. It needs to function on its own and does not have any CSS tags for divs.

I have a website with a centered pane that I'm working on, but the text aligns to the box, when I set a limit on the width of it, it goes to that paragraph width but automatically goes to the left of the 900PX content radius. Here's an example of what I'm talking about;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<p style="width:850px;"><font color="#000000">
<font face="calibri"><p align="center">BEEP</p>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For html W3C standard validation you have to write your code within body tag like this:
this will be your perfect code:
    
    
    
    
    Untitled Document

```
<body>
<p style="text-align:center; width:850px; color:#000000; font-family:calibri;">BEEP</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

```
<div align="center"><div style="width:600px;">
```